# Convert a For loop to a lambda expression in Java

Tags: java, loops, lambda

I have the following code

```
//assume we have a list of custom type "details" already constructed 

 for(int i = 0; i < details.size(); ++i) {
    CallerID number = details.get(i).getNextNumber();
    ClientData.addToClient(number);
                
 }
```

I have oversimplified the code. The enum CallerID and the ClientData object work as intended. I am asking for help converting this loop to a lambda function so I can understand the logic of how to do so, then fill in the appropriate code as needed.

Comment: Assuming that is actually `details.get(i)` this looks like a `map` followed by a `forEach`.

Comment: fixed the typo. I am getting the elements in a list (using a method that converts it to be stored by the enum CallerID) and then adding it to a ClientData object.

Comment: yes, sorry about that. Fixed it

Comment: Also, I suppose by "lambda" you actually meant "using the Stream API". Is that right? If that's the case, I stand by my initial comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am asking for help converting this loop to a lambda function so I can understand the logic of how to do so, then fill in the appropriate code as needed.

A `Function` returns a value.  As you are just updating something what you need is a `Consumer` which accepts a single argument of a list of some detail.  Assuming those are in a `Class` named `SomeDetails`, here is how you would do it.

As you iterating over some structure limited by `size` and using `get(i)` I am presuming a list is required here.

```
List<SomeDetails> details = new ArrayList<>(); // then populated

// lambda definition
Consumer<List<SomeDetails>> update = (lst)-> {
            for(SomeDetails detail : lst) {
                  CallerID number = detail.getNextNumber();
                  ClientData.addToClient(number);
            }
};
```

And then invoke it like this, passing the List.

```
update.accept(details);
```

All the above does is encapsulate the for loop (using the enhanced version for simplicity) and perform the operation.

If this is all you wanted, I would recommend just doing it as you were doing it sans the lambda.

Answer (score 3):

Let's first write it as a modern basic for loop and golf it a bit, just so we're comparing apples to apples:

```
for (var detail : details) clientData.addToClient(detail.getNextNumber());
```

And this is probably the right answer. It is local var, exception, and control flow transparent (which is what you want), and short.

The lambda form is this, but it's got downsides (mostly, those transparencies). It also isn't any shorter. You shouldn't write it this way.

```
details.stream().forEach(d -> clientData.addToClient(detail.getNextNumber());
```

You may be able to just remove `stream()` from that. But probably not.

Generally when people say "I want it in lambda form", that's not because someone is holding a gun to your head - you are saying that because somebody peddling a religion of sorts to you told you that 'it was better' and that this 'will scale'. Realize that they are full of it. There can be advantages to 'functional style', but **none of these snippets are functional**. A true functional style would involve a bunch of side-effect-free transformations, and then *returning* something.

`.addToClient`? You've lost the functional game there - you would want to instead convert each `detail` to something (presumably a `ClientID`), and from there construct an immutable object from that stream. You'd 'collect' your ClientIDs into a `clientData` object.

Let's say for example that `clientData` is just a 'list of ClientIDs' and nothing more. Then you'd write something like this:

```
var clientData = details.stream()
  .map(MyDetailClass::getNextNumber)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is this *better*? No. However, if you're looking for 'a stream-style, lambda-based functional take on things', that qualifies. The output is constructed by way of collection (and not `forEach` that does a side-effect operation), and all elements involved are (or can be) immutable.

There's no particular reason why you'd want this, but if for some reason you're convinced this is better, now you know what you want to do. "Just replace it with a lambda" doesn't make it 'functional'.

Comment: Note: with actual Java version, the whole `collect(...)` can be replaces by `toList()`

Comment: can I ask, when is it necessary or good to use ```.map()```? I see that you use it in one sample solution and not in the other.

Comment: `map` turns one thing into another, and fits the functional model: It has no side-effects, and can be trivially parallelized. `forEach` does a thing per item and then just ends. By definition if the 'a thing' has no side effects, nothing happens at all. Hence, if you write `forEach`, it's no longer 'pure functional', according to most definitions (and admittedly, there are _a lot_ of conflicting definitions of what that even means; as this answer gets into, trying to paint one of these as somehow 'fundamentally better' because it is more 'pure' is a bit of a slippery slope).